# Escaping PHP string

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to add a php session into the content as shown below, but it's just showing an empty page. I'm sure the escaping is not correct.

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=$_SESSION['name'];\">";
```

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

```
$_SESSION['name'] = 'somepage.php'
```

And I want to add the session into the url so it redirects to 'somepage'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to combine html quotes and variables is to do it in following way:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $_SESSION['name'] . ';">';
```

Comment: +1 Suggest also adding in `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` to stop unexpected values from breaking the HTML output.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to learn how [variables are parsed inside PHP strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

```
// do not use single quotes
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=$_SESSION[name]\">";

// curly brackets syntax works too but requires quotes; useful in cases when
// variable name is immediately followed by alpha-numeric/underscore character(s)
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL={$_SESSION['name']}\">";

// curly brackets alternate syntax
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=${_SESSION['name']}\">";
```

Personally, I like using `sprintf()`:

```
echo sprintf("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=%s\">", $_SESSION['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

inside of a double quoted "smart" string you cannot have a referenced array inside only single variables.

Try This:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=".$_SESSION['name'].";\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $_SESSION['name'] . ';">';
```

or use

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/" . $_SESSION['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=".$_SESSION['name'].";\">";
```

Should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=" . $_SESSION['name'] . ";\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why noone mentioned `(s)printf`

```
printf('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=%s;">', $_SESSION['name']);
```

This gets very useful once you need to output many variables in text. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).